# How would I get a count of the output records (rows/lines) AFTER going through a Muenchian Group

Tags: xslt, muenchian-grouping

Here are two entries in the xml.  There are thousands of these.

```
<Export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Record>
    <AccountNo>700101030</AccountNo>
    <Amount>9166.67</Amount>
    <PayDate>20230714</PayDate>
    <PPEndDate>07/15/2023</PPEndDate>
    <Description>Regular                                       </Description>
    <Category>Earning</Category>
    <Desc>Regular</Desc>
    <EmpNumber>1800411</EmpNumber>
    <EmpFirstName>Denis</EmpFirstName>
    <EmpLastName>Chevalier</EmpLastName>
    <DeptName>0839865300</DeptName>
    <OnSiteName>0839865300 - New York 1 Columbus Circle - 0839</OnSiteName>
    <LedgerCode>0839865300</LedgerCode>
    <Constant1>ERN</Constant1>
    <Filler1>                         </Filler1>
    <Filler2>                  </Filler2>
</Record>
<Record>
    <AccountNo>283410165</AccountNo>
    <Amount>-6.24</Amount>
    <PayDate>20230714</PayDate>
    <PPEndDate>07/15/2023</PPEndDate>
    <Description>Vision Pretax                                 </Description>
    <Category>Deduction</Category>
    <Desc>Vision Pretax</Desc>
    <EmpNumber>1800411</EmpNumber>
    <EmpFirstName>Denis</EmpFirstName>
    <EmpLastName>Chevalier</EmpLastName>
    <DeptName>0839865300</DeptName>
    <OnSiteName>0839865300 - New York 1 Columbus Circle - 0839</OnSiteName>
    <DeptOverride>6201350008</DeptOverride>
    <LedgerCode>0839865300</LedgerCode>
    <Constant1>DED</Constant1>
    <Filler1>                         </Filler1>
    <Filler2>                  </Filler2>
</Record>
```

Here is the body of the xslt:

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
<xsl:key name="kRcdGroup" match="Export/Record" use="concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo, Description, vb:GetOverrideCode(DeptOverride,LedgerCode))"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Export">

    <!-- Header Record -->
    <xsl:value-of select="'01'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="vb:GetDate()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'BT        '"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'PayrollNew2    '"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>

    <!-- Detail Records -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kRcdGroup',concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo, Description, vb:GetOverrideCode(DeptOverride,LedgerCode)))[1])] ">            

        <xsl:variable name="vkeyGroup" select="key('kRcdGroup', concat(generate-id(..), AccountNo, Description, vb:GetOverrideCode(DeptOverride,LedgerCode))) "/>
        <xsl:variable name="SumPos">
            <xsl:if test="Amount > 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($vkeyGroup/Amount),'#.00')"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="SumNeg">
            <xsl:if test="Amount &lt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($vkeyGroup/Amount)*-1,'#.00')"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="orc">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(vb:GetOverrideCode(DeptOverride,LedgerCode),1,4)"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Data output -->
        <xsl:value-of select="'02    '"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$orc"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="PayDate"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="PayDate"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'IX'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Amount > 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="'40'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'50'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="vb:PadR(Constant1,' ',4)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Amount > 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="'S'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'H'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="'USD    '"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Amount > 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="vb:PadL($SumPos,' ',14)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="vb:PadL(translate($SumNeg,'-',''),' ',14)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="vb:PadR(' ',' ',25)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="vb:PadR(AccountNo,' ',28)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($orc,vb:GetOverrideCode(DeptOverride,LedgerCode))"/>
        <xsl:text>&#x0D;&#x0A;</xsl:text>

    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- Footer Record -->
    <xsl:value-of select="'99'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(/Export/Record/Description),'#####')"/>
    <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
    
</xsl:template>
```

Everything is working fine except the footer.  The count returns the number of description nodes based on the input BUT, I need the count to be AFTER the grouping occurs.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you, Greg Gregerson

Comment: For a [mre], please post root of your XSLT especially since you use a namespace prefix, `vb`.

Comment: Why not simply count the distinct keys in footer? A fuller XML sample representative of multiple groups would be a worthwhile [mre].

Comment: Thanks Parfait.  I tried doing a count using my group key but it said it is out of scope.  How would I do that "simply count the distinct keys".  I have learned xslt primarily from looking at other scripts written by other authors and the internet.  Most of it deals with XML or HTML transformation where as my work is always tabular text output for input into another system.  Please help.  Thanks, Greg